# Thousands of TimeoutExceptions after switching to Redis Enterprise

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

We recently attempted to switch from Azure Redis to Redis Enterprise, unfortunately after about an hour we were forced to roll back due to performance issues.  We're looking for advice on how to get to the root cause and proceed.  Here's what I've figured out so far, but I'm happy to add any more details as necessary.

First off, the client is a .NET Framework app using StackExchange.Redis version 2.1.30.  The Azure Redis instance is using 4 shards, and the Redis Enterprise instance is also configured for 4 shards.

When we switched over to Redis Enterprise, we would immediately see several thousand of these exceptions per 5 minute interval:

> Timeout performing GET (5000ms), next: GET [Challenges]::306331, inst:
> 1, qu: 0, qs: 3079, aw: False, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0,
> serverEndpoint: xxxxxxx:17142, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 9 of 10 available,
> clientName: API, IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=400,Max=1000), WORKER:
> (Busy=112,Free=32655,Min=2000,Max=32767), Local-CPU: 4.5%, v:
> 2.1.30.38891 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts:
> https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

Looking at this error message, it appears there's tons of things in the WORKER thread pool (things waiting on a response from Redis Enterprise), but nearly nothing in the IOCP thread pool (responses from Redis waiting to be processed by our client code).  So, there's some sort of bottleneck on the Redis side.

Using AppInsights, I created a graph of the busy worker threads (dark blue), busy IO threads (red), and CPU usage (light blue).  We see something like this:

[image]

The CPU never really goes above 20% or so, the IO threads are barely a blip (I think the max is like 2 busy), but the worker threads kinda grow and grow until eventually everything times out and the process starts over again.  A little after 7pm is when we decided to roll back to Azure Redis, so everything is great at that point.  So, everything points to Redis being some sort of bottleneck.  So, let's look at the Redis side of things.

During this time, Redis reported a max of around 5% CPU usage.  Incoming traffic topped out around 1.4MB/s, and outgoing traffic topped out around 9.5MB/s.  Ops/sec were around 4k.  Latency around this time was 0.05ms, and the slowest thing in the SLOWLOG was like 15ms or so.  In other words, the Redis Enterprise node was barely breaking a sweat and was easily able to keep up with the traffic being sent to it.  In fact, we had 4 other nodes in the cluster that weren't even being used since Redis didn't even see the need to send anything to other nodes.  Redis was basically just yawning.

From here, I was thinking maybe there were network bandwidth contraints.  All of our VMs are configured for accelerated networking, and we should have 10gig connections to these machines.  I decided to run an *iperf* between the client and the server:

[image]

I can transfer easily over 700Mbit/sec between the client and the Redis Enterprise server, yet the server is processing 9.5MB/sec easily.  So, it doesn't appear the problem is network bandwidth.

So, here's where we stand:

- The same code works great with Azure Redis, yet causes thousands of timeouts when we switch over to Redis Enterprise.
- Redis Enterprise is handling 4,000 operations per second and sending out 9 megs a second, and can usually handle a single operation in a fraction of a ms, with the very longest being 15ms.
- I can send 700+ Mb/sec between the client and server.
- Yet, the WORKER thread pool builds up with pending requests to Redis and eventually times out.

I'm pretty stuck here.  What's a good next step to diagnose this issue?  Thanks!

Comment: Since you're using Redis Enterprise,  they should offer some support to their paid cusomters. Have you contacted them yet?

Comment: Yup, we filed a ticket.  I'm guessing they won't be able to help a lot since all metrics indicate their software is super fast.

Comment: I would try 1. connect to Redis Enterprise with a redis-benchmark (included with a redis installation), run some test for a long time, see if there's any timeout. If not, it probably means something needs to be tweaked with your .net redis client.   2. Pressure test with your .net redis client, with simeple GET SET commands and monitor timeout errors.

Comment: Yea, we already ran redis-benchmark and we get something like 70,000 operations per second (which seems to match the bandwidth limits on the VM).  On our client, we get a little over 1,000 operations per second and things time out.  If we have to start making big changes to our code, we'll probably pull the plug on Redis Enterprise and go back to using Azure Redis, since it works fine already.

Comment: You can try tweak the your client's config like thread pool and timeout options, retry, etc.

Comment: As you can see with the exception, there's no issues with the IO threads and worker threads are what's busy, but there's plenty of them..

Comment: @MikeChristensen Did you guys manage to figure out the issue, we're running into similar issues and we're ditching Redis Enterprise in favor of Azure Redis.

Comment: @ken  Hah! I'm here to make the EXACT same comment. We're ditching it right as I type this. Same problems -- qs queue blocked waiting for thousands of responses while Redis Enterprise is barely at 1% cpu.

Comment: @ken Nope, never figured this one out and we went back to Azure Redis.  That little "experiment" cost us $30 grand.  Their support simply blamed it on our code and wasn't familiar enough with .NET to help us out.

Comment: @MikeChristensen What a bummer, thx for your reply. We stopped using redis all together for now as we were having issue with bother Azure Redis and the enterprise version.

Comment: @ken I noticed Redis is really good for storing very small values, like a few hundred bytes.  If you try to store tens of thousands of bytes, or even hundreds of thousands of bytes, it turns into a complete disaster..  We really abuse it, but probably if we fixed all that we wouldn't need Redis Enterprise in the first place..

Comment: @MikeChristensen Good to know. Thx for the heads up buddy